# Insert multiple rows in Oracle using VB6

Tags: sql, oracle, vb6, ora-00933, ora-00911

I am trying to insert multiple rows in a table using BeginTrans...CommitTrans.
Below is code snippet:

```
For i = 1 To 5
    SQL = SQL & "Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col" & i & "','Col" & i + 1 & "','Col" & i + 2 & "')" & vbCrLf
Next i
conn.BeginTrans
    conn.Execute SQL
conn.CommitTrans
```

and following is the SQL prepared using the loop

```
Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col1','Col2','Col3')
Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col2','Col3','Col4')
Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col3','Col4','Col5')
Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col4','Col5','Col6')
Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col5','Col6','Col7')
```

When I run `conn.CommitTrans` I get ORA-00911: Invalid character

If I modify the SQL as

```
Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col1','Col2','Col3');
Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col2','Col3','Col4');
Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col3','Col4','Col5');
Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col4','Col5','Col6');
Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col5','Col6','Col7');
```

I get ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended.
If I update further and replace ";" with "/" again get same error
Any help is greatly appreciated.
ThanX in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified what TestTable actually is (type of fields, etc).  However, I would start by seeing if you can type the insert command into a standard Oracle client (e.g. TOAD)?

If you can't then check for any triggers or constraints on the table.

Answer (score 1):

You probably need to execute each statement separately, e.g.:

```
conn.BeginTrans
For i = 1 To 5
    SQL = "Insert into TestTable(Field1,Field2,Field3) Values ('Col" & i & "','Col" & i + 1 & "','Col" & i + 2 & "')"
    conn.Execute SQL
Next i
conn.CommitTrans
```